# How can I undo a specific action in Arena chess?

Tags: arena

I opened a game in Arena. And removed a move/variation. If I want to undo it, is there any option in Arena to do that? Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> does not work.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be possible and I'm not sure why... Ctrl+Z is a shortcut for Game → Move now.

Comment: It is such a basic feature and I am surprised why it is not there.